# Running same tests against a large number of websites

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a need to run the same tests against over 70 websites which are all functionally the same but have different skins. They are all accessed through different URLs however.

Using TestNG and Java, What would be an efficient way to pass the URLs to the tests so that I can:
a) run each test against each site and report on same
b) execute tests in parallel to save time (future need)

I want to store the URLs in a format such that it is exposed to end users and configurable by them.  This would ideally be in a .csv or alternatively, as  in the testng.xml file. I am thinking either @DataProvider or @Factory but am unsure how to use these in an efficient and maintainable way to take parameters from an external source or where in my current model such methods would be best placed?  The difficulty I have is that I don't want to pass the data necessarily into @Test's, rather pass in one value at a time (a url) and run against all @Test annotated methods.

My current simple setup is as follows:

```
testngxml:
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
<test name="FindARouteTest">
    <parameter name="number" value="1"/>
    <parameter name="from" value="LONDON"/>
    <parameter name="to" value="GLASGOW"/>
    <parameter name="emailAddress" value="test@example.co.uk"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="acceptancetests.EndToEndTest">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

My acceptance test:

```
public class EndToEndTest extends DriverBase{

private HomePage home;
private String url;

@Factory(dataProvider = "urls", dataProviderClass = URLProvider.class)
public EndToEndTest(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}


@BeforeSuite
public void stuff(){
    newDriver();
}


@BeforeClass
public void setup(){
    home = new HomePage(driver, url);
}

@Test (priority = 1)
@Parameters({"from","to"})
public void searchForARoute(String from, String to) throws InterruptedException {
    home.selectWhereFrom(from);
    home.selectWhereTo(to);
    //some assertions...
```

My PageObject:

```
public class HomePage extends SeleniumBase {

public HomePage(WebDriver driver, String url) {
    super(driver, url);
    try {
        visit(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

public void someMethodOrOther(){
//some methods...
```

My Selenium Methods BasePage:

```
public class SeleniumBase implements Config {

public WebDriver driver;
public String url;

public SeleniumBase(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.url = url;
}

public void visit() throws MalformedURLException {
    driver.get(url);
} //more methods...
```

My Driver Base Page:

```
public class DriverBase implements Config {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static String url;

    protected void newDriver() {
        if (host.equals("localhost")) {
            if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                        System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
                FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
//more stuff
```

URL Provider class:

```
public class URLProvider {

@DataProvider(name = "urls")
public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod()
{
    return new Object[][] {{"http://siteone.com"},
                            {"http://sitetwo.com"},
                            {"http://sitethree.com"}
    };
}
}
```

Finally, a Config which currently holds only a BaseUrl:

```
public interface Config {

String baseUrl = System.getProperty("baseUrl", 
String browser = System.getProperty("browser", "chrome");
String host = System.getProperty("host", "localhost");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the @Factory annotation on the constructor for test class EndToEndTest and give it a dataprovider.

```
private String url;

@Factory(dataProvider = "urls", dataProviderClass = URLProvider.class)
public EndToEndTest(String url) {
  this.url = url;
}
```

You need to provide the implementation of the URL data provider class to access the excel or whatever file you want and return an Object[][].

Need to modify the constructors of HomePage and SeleniumBase to pass in the url which you are calling from your @BeforeClass method.

This should create a separate instance for this test class for every url string and call the @Test methods.

If you need to pass in more data than a string URL you can use an object instead. As I can see your passing 4 parameters in your testng.xml for a method.

Parallelism should be pretty simple, guessing you would want to run all the @Test methods for a given url in a single thread. The parallel option would be "classes".

Comment: thank you for the detailed reply - I will try your suggestions and will let you know how I get on

Comment: this works well, but debugging with x3 urls in the URLProvider.class,  I can see that '@Factory' annotated constructor is called 3 times (once for each parameter) before '@BeforeClass' and this means 3 threads? I believe, and 3 browser windows with the tests running in parallel.  To start with, I would like each url to be passed, all '@Tests' run against one url and then fetch the next one. So, pass in one URL to EndtoEnd constructor, run tests and then fetch the next - not sure how this is possible.

Comment: As I understand you want it to run serially, one URL after the other. Not parallel. Is that correct? Just remove the parallel option from your testng.xml or tests and it will run one after the other.

Comment: sorry yes, serially to start with but want to investigate parallel in future. Currently, I do not have parallel in the testng.xml nor in the tests.  I will update the code snippets to show current implementation

Comment: So you want that instead of 3 browser windows opening and closing, you want the test to be run serially in one browser window. If so then in EndToEndTest class create a new method and annotate with 'BeforeSuite' and move the newDriver() call from the current 'BeforeClass' method to this new method. Also make sure you close or quit the browser in the 'AfterSuite' method. Remove any driver closing from AfterClass method. It should in theory only open one browser window for the whole suite of tests.

Comment: Saw the updated code, should work with the changes mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: what actually happens in this case, is that it runs @BeforeClass x3 times - once for each url - before it hits the Tests. This means each URL is loaded into the same browser window before any tests are run.  So I still need a means to read only 1 url into the class at a time, open a browser, run the tests then load the next url, run the tests etc...

Comment: Can you try this on google chrome. I tried something similar to your code this on on firefox and chrome. Worked correctly on chrome but bombed as you described on firefox. Got to check that out. Interesting!

Comment: thinking about this, it is going to be impractical to run end to end in a single thread/browser so having them run in parallel is probably ideal. I just need to tweak them to a. limit the number of browsers to a reasonable  number and b. have the testng report the name of the url tested instead of the thread number.  Thank you for your help - voting up original answer