# How to run an entire test suite with Selenium & JUnit 5 on different URLs

Tags: java, selenium, testing, junit, automation

I have a test class that currently uses parameterized tests to run each test on different URLs. However I want the output to be in the form

### Url

- Failed Test 1
- Failed Test 2

instead of

### Test

- Failed URL 1
- Failed URL 2

I can accomplish this by having a seperate class for each URL but there are over 300 URLs so that's not really an option. The classes would be the same except for paremters though so:

1. Is there a way to do this in JUnit (essentially I want to parameterize the whole class) if not:
2. Would log4j be able to accomplish this if not:
3. Is there a way to make the classes at runtime automatically if not:
4. What testing framework can accomplish this, I am open to any software that can do this

My problem is similar to this: [Running same tests against a large number of websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854508/running-same-tests-against-a-large-number-of-websites)

Comment: Use the Parameterized runner with junit. Refer to this https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks for the reply! Won't that just run each test case for every url instead of running every test case for each url.

I'll be clearer on what I want: With parameterized tests it runs like test 1 - url 1, test 1 - url 2, test 1 - url 3

I want: url 1 - test 1, url 1 - test 2, url 2 - test 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the below parameterized test class and got the result. All tests for a parameter are executed before next parameter is used.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParamTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Object[] data() {
        return new Object[] { "google", "yahoo", "facebook" };
    }

    @Parameter
    public String url;

    @Test()
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Test 1 - "+url);
    }

    @Test()
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Test 2 - "+url);
    }
}
```

---

```
Test 1 - google
Test 2 - google
Test 1 - yahoo
Test 2 - yahoo
Test 1 - facebook
Test 2 - facebook
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this in JUnit 5? Or a way to read in parameters from a csv?

Comment: Refer to this article covers everything u can do with parameterized junit tests- https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-writing-parameterized-tests/